# How to diaplay other tables attributes in single view form and also insert values in corresponding tables

Tags: database, yii

I have two tables QBQuestion(Questionid,Question,OptionId) and Option(OptionId,Option). I want to display option form on view form of QBQuestion? I want to create multiple choice question. i.e.for single question we can add multiple options.For such purpose i want to cretae option field with add button si that when we click add button,we can insert more options and also want to display that all inserted options in table using grid.
So what should i do? please help me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Add relations in the model for this two stuff.

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'valOptions' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Option', 'OptionId'),
    );
}
```

2) Use lazy loading in CGridView.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => new CActiveDataProvider('QBQuestion'),
    'columns' => array(
        'Questionid',
        'Question',
        'valOptions.Option',
    ),
));
```

I think that's what you need.

Comment: Thanx for your Quick reply..but before creating grid when i am inserting value in option field,,then that inserted value is not getting stored in option table. So what changes i need to make in actionCreate or other related method so that my inserted options through QBQuestion view will get sored in Option table's option Field.

Comment: I don't understand your meaning, but you can use $optioModel->insert() to insert the data to Option tables. and it will return the option id, then you can use the id insert the record to Question table.